# Can you move/copy SharePoint 2016 site collections with a content database detach/attach or site collection backup/restore into a different domain?

Tags: sharepoint-server, migration

We have about 10 fairly large (100 GB - 200 GB) site collections on SharePoint 2016 and we need to move these into another farm in another company.  I know with database detach/attach and site collection backup/restore options the version/CU of SharePoint matters.  If we can get those to match properly, is there a way to map users to a new domain?

I know that migration tools can do this with basically a CSOM approach, but it seems that a content database detach/attach may be the quickest option if I can overcome the user mapping complication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Move-SPUser` or `stsadm -o migrateuser` to migrate from one account to another (if using Windows claims, make sure you pass the `-IgnoreSID` switch for `Move-SPUser`).

There are other tools, such as Sharegate, which allow you to remap user accounts from one object to another.

Comment: Thanks, Trevor.  So an approach might be to detach/attach the content database from one domain/company to the other, then run Move-SPUser after in the new environment?

Comment: That's correct.